# Ionic 3 Module Declarations Error

Tags: angular, cordova, module, ionic3

Running the command below works:
`ionic cordova build ios`

But running the following

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod
```

results in the following error

> Error: Type ExpandableHeaderComponent in
>   /Users/jobstore/jobstore/js/src/components/expandable-header/expandable-header.ts
>   is part of the declarations of 2 modules: SharedModuleComponent in
>   /Users/jobstore/jobstore/js/src/components/shared-module/shared-module.ts
>   and ExpandableHeaderComponentModule in
>   /Users/jobstore/jobstore/js/src/components/expandable-header/expandable-header.module.ts!
>   Please consider moving ExpandableHeaderComponent in
>   /Users/jobstore/jobstore/js/src/components/expandable-header/expandable-header.ts
>   to a higher module that imports SharedModuleComponent in
>   /Users/jobstore/jobstore/js/src/components/shared-module/shared-module.ts
>   and ExpandableHeaderComponentModule in
>   /Users/jobstore/jobstore/js/src/components/expandable-header/expandable-header.module.ts.
>   You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes
>   ExpandableHeaderComponent in
>   /Users/jobstore/jobstore/js/src/components/expandable-header/expandable-header.ts
>   then import that NgModule in SharedModuleComponent in
>   /Users/jobstore/jobstore/js/src/components/shared-module/shared-module.ts
>   and ExpandableHeaderComponentModule in
>   /Users/jobstore/jobstore/js/src/components/expandable-header/expandable-header.module.ts.

I tried creating a shared module :

```
import { Component ,NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {ExpandableHeaderComponent} from '../expandable-header/expandable-header';
import {ShrinkHeaderComponent} from '../shrink-header/shrink-header';


@Component({
    selector: 'shared-module',
    templateUrl: 'shared-module.html'
})



@NgModule({
    declarations: [
    ExpandableHeaderComponent,
    ShrinkHeaderComponent

    ],

    exports: [
    ExpandableHeaderComponent,
    ShrinkHeaderComponent
    ]

})

export class SharedModuleComponent {

    constructor() {
    }

}
```

and importing it in app.module.ts

here

```
  import { SharedModuleComponent } from '../components/shared-module/shared-module';
```

and here

```
      imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     HttpModule,
   SharedModuleComponent,
     ],
```

but i still face the same issue.

Comment: Your error states exactly what you should do. What is unclear here?

Comment: Can you show your ComponentsModule?

Comment: @yurzui, can you please just help me understand

Comment: @brijmcq, Sorry I undated the question with the correct error message. I just kept trying random things.

Comment: Your code is incomplete with the new error. Though you can fix it by just declaring in one module only. By sharing more of your code, I can help you out

Answer (score 0):

The error tells what you need to do. In addition to this, I noticed that you create another module just for `ExpandableHeaderComponent`. If you are not lazy-loading your modules, it is better to just declare it in your `SharedModule` or straight to your `AppModule`

Comment: my ExpandableHeaderComponent was initially just called in the AppModule, but when i ran the app in --prod. It threw the same error, so I made a sharedModule. But it's not working

Comment: I guess I don't understand when the error says import to a higher module. What does that mean exactly ?

Comment: It is difficult to say with the info you provided. Basically, you should only declare it in one module either your sharedmodule or appmodule. You probably missing something

Comment: it means that you are importing it in the ExpandableHeaderComponentModule  instead of sharedmodule/appmodule. Just like what i've said in my answer, you seemed to create another module just for ExpandableHeaderComponent

Comment: I realised what the issue is, but then noticed that in all my files where I generted the pages: ionic cordova -g pages ABC, a abc.modules.ts file was created. When I remove those pages the command runs fine. Do you know why this happens ?

Comment: Do you mean ionic generate? It just generates a component and not a module.